# Javascript - Static HTML has different DOM properties than dynamically generated

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a spreadsheet-like app that allows for easy navigation with arrow keys.  This requires me to set a 'pointer' which is just a reference to a certain HTML element.  I start off the page by loading in two rows and I give the user the option to generate new rows.  These new rows receive event listeners when generated.

So if you hit an arrow key, the pointer should move around to adjacent cells.  I use the childNodes property of the parent class of a given cell (which is the row it resides in) to locate an adjacent cell + using indexOf to figure out what the current cell's position is.  So moving up means I need to go to the parent cells previous sibling and then to the same index of that HTMLCollection.

However, the first two rows I generate from static HTML have different properties than dynamically generated rows.  They automatically start off with these useless text nodes between the actual input boxes.  As a result, I can't just select the next sibling, I have to skip two siblings over.  But this is different from dynamic content because when I dynamically generate it, it doesn't have these text nodes (pic related).

I would force the user to dynamically generate it from the beginning (without starting them off with 2 rows) but the idea is to use a templating engine on the server side to generate previously entered data retrieved from a database, which should behave the same way as hard-coded HTML.   Ergo, these cells will behave differently from the new rows that the user wants to generate and the navigation function breaks.

Is there a way to generate new HTML from javascript so that it acts just like static HTML?

Pic 1:  DOM properties of static HTML

Pic 2:  DOM properties of dynamically generated HTML (text nodes normally do not exist at all, but I tried to mimic the static HTML and tried inserting text nodes between the input cells but this doesn't work)

[image: These are the relevant DOM properties of the static HTML. It has 13 childNodes but only 6 children and that's because the static HTML is putting text nodes in between the actual input cells. These elements, however, do not exist on the DOM and even when I hover over them, it doesn't highlight anything on the window like normal elements do.]

[image: And these are the properties of the row containing the dynamically generated cells. I tried to mimic the previous one by adding text cells (so as to preserve the index order) between each actual input cell but this breaks when I try to do vertical movement and I've narrowed it down to this. Removing the text node appends will fix vertical movement but breaks horizontal movement.]

Comment: I would suspect the additional text nodes are whitespaces between your tags?

Comment: A more holistic approach to your problem would be to make an SPA(Single Page Application) and render the first rows with existing content from your backend via an API call. That way you use the very same methods to generate your rows each time even if the data comes from the backend. I would also observe that from the sound of your description you should look at a better API structure of your app. There should be one API for selecting cells that takes an address (row, column) and on down arrow all you do is `select( currentCol, currentRow + 1)` etc

Comment: Oh wow, yeah that seemed to be the problem (the line breaks were actually causing it, I didn't have other spaces).  I now have this ugly block of input tags in my HTML but luckily it's only a small section.  Do you mean a better API structure for the cell navigation?  Not sure how I can find the column

Comment: If it makes a difference, my back-end is not Javascript.  It's Laravel.  So i'm not sure if I can still make the 'very same method' call.

Comment: Well there are many approaches out there you can read up on. Namely the most recent and most commonly used one is something called virtual DOM. Others are storing pointers in your DOM nodes etc. Glad it worked out in the end. Good luck

Comment: Thanks again.  If you'd like, you can post an answer and I'd be glad to give you the points for your answer.

Comment: The idea of separating the backend from the fronend means it doesn't matter what languages they're both written in. If you use your frontend code to generate your first couple of rows from an API call that your Laravel backend sends you make sure all rows are created equal. This might be a chat for another day :)

Comment: Indeed, I will try to digest what you said and do some more reading about the things you mentioned, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text nodes in your statically generated HTML would be the whitespace you have generated between each tag. That whitespace does have an impact on your DOM although a small one. You js generated HTML will likely not have any whitespace which is why your two versions differ a bit. Make sure you static and dynamic HTML is the very same including whitespace and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

The text nodes you see are empty spaces. If you want to get rid of the textnodes in your static HTML you would have to minify it so there are no new lines or spaces but I do not recommend this as it would be hard to work on during development.

To get rid of the text nodes you would have to get rid of them and then apply your event to each one. You can do this in several ways.

```
var removeTextNodes = array => [...array].filter(item => item.nodeType !== 3 );
// the array being your nodeList 
// removes all the textnodes and turns it into a real array using 
// spread operator 

removeTextNodes.forEach((cell) => cell.addEventListener('keypress', hightLightCell); 
// I would also recommend that you add a removeEventListener in your hightLightCell function as this could slow down your app
```

Or you could use the `children` selector instead of `childNodes` because this will not include empty text nodes/spaces in your node.

```
var cells = document.querySelector('.parent-div').children; 
// this will get you a nodeList with no empty text nodes
```